# Columns CSS Property and Google Maps in Chrome (Bug or not?)

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome

I have a curious problem, Maybe someone can help me to fix it or understand it. I don't know if it is a bug or there are way to solve this but I'm building a layout with the css3 property `columns`, and everything its ok in Firefox and Safari, but in Google Chrome, the maps events(drag) are overlaping my other columns, you can see the problem in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bcwfqxp5/ or running this snippet:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
  });
});
```

```css
.twoColumns {
  columns: 2;
}

.twoColumns>* {
  break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.anyContent {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}

#map_div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div class="twoColumns">
  <div class="anyContent">Why can I drag here in Chrome?</div>
  <div id="map_div" style="height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

> Note: This works ok in Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 0):

For these types of layout issues I always look at the HTML first, and I noticed you had both objects in the same div, and it worked when I split them into two divs.

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
  });
});
```

```css
.twoColumns {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.anyContent {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#map_div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.google-maps {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .google-maps iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="twoColumns">
  <div class="anyContent">Why can I drag here in Chrome?</div>
</div>
<div class="twoColumns">
  <div id="map_div" style="height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I know that the minimal example can works with other layouts like flex, or inline block, but I want to use columns because I need to separate my content in columns automatically without make manual breaks.

Comment: I've used your columns layout classes.

Comment: I'm mean to use `columns` css3 property, It distribute my content in columns automatically.

Comment: css grid allows for this overlap: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout (go about halfway down the page) and you can control it with z-index

Comment: There are webkit classes for columns but they had no effect. I'll delete my answer if it's not helpful, let me know.

Comment: I've seen the grid layout, but I don't know how many blocks my container can have, that's why I let the `columns` automatically distribute the elements in two rows, I've also tried other properties, but the problem persists, it seems to be a Chrome bug. Please, Do not delete your answer yet, so other people can see what we've talked about. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's funny Chrome recognises the columns visually but doesn't treat them as containing block elements. I tried some browser-specific tags but to no avail. I'll leave my answer here no worries.